# Module not found error for self made library

Tags: python, module, shared-libraries, libraries

I made a library named `converttxttoxml` (https://pypi.org/project/converttxttoxml/0.0.2/) but everytime someone tries to run it a error of `module not found` pops up after successful installation of library.

```
import converttxttoxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'converttxttoxml'
```

But running totally fine in my pc.

Comment: Is your library located in the regular python folder?

Comment: yes, the library is located in the regular python folder